# how does hexadecimal to decimal work in swift?

Tags: swift, hex

Swift documentation has `let hexadecimalDouble = 0xC.3p0` which apparently equals 12.1875.. Maybe I'm not understanding something with the notation, but I'm not sure how 12.1875 is derived, specifically the '1875' part.

Comment: If you would like to write that in Swift it would look like `(12 * pow(Double(16),0) + 3/pow(Double(16),1)) * pow(Double(2),0)`. Note that anything powered zero equals 1 and anything powered to 1 remains the same. Therefore it can also be written as `12.0 + 3/16`

Comment: If you would like to expand on that `0xCE.FEAp2` equals `827.978515625` which can also be written in Swift as `(12.0 * pow(Double(16),1) + 14 * pow(Double(16),0) + 15/pow(Double(16),1) + 14/pow(Double(16),2) + 10/pow(Double(16),3)) * pow(Double(2),2)` or simply `(12.0 * 16 + 14 + 15/16 + 14/pow(Double(16),2) + 10/pow(Double(16),3)) * pow(Double(2),2)`